# Apps installed on iPhone when installing on iPad

Tags: ipad, apple-id, enterprise, ipados, mdm

My employer uses the Blackberry UEM client to control our BYOD devices.   I was enrolled in this program until they changed their BYOD management policies.   I then dis-enrolled my device.   I was not comfortable with them changing the password policies on my phone, requiring periodic password changes and being able to sync contacts and remote wipe, so I picked up an iPad for work purposes.

The iPad had me bring my phone near the device during initial setup, and was able to set up my Apple ID with no problem.  I did not migrate my apps or data.   I installed the Blackberry UEM client and it proceeded to do all the annoying changes on my iPad.  All good.

My surprise was when I went back to my iPhone, there were new applications installed on it.  Three UEM components "Connectivity", "Access", "Symphony", and some MS Office components "Teams", "Business", "AIP Viewer".

There were however also applications that I installed on the iPad without using the UEM client: "Powerpoint" and the "Visio Viewer"... although come to think of it I may have *attempted* to install them using the UEM and failed.

These are not *all* the UEM components from the iPad... which is also weird.

The Blackberry apps seem to be unconfigured and unusable.  The MS office components have no license, so operate only as viewers.

My concern is:

- how could these apps have been installed on my iPhone?
- How do I ensure that the remote wipe capabilities etc, cannot act on my iPhone?

I hesitate on this question because it's a bit tech-support like, but the control of my own devices is important to me.  A tech support L1 would certainly tell me in an abundance of caution and lack of knowledge, that yes, magic connects everything and I need a new Apple ID on the iPad or something, but I'm hoping to find a more technical answer as to how I can ensure that my iPhone (and Macbook??) can't be controlled via UEM's grasp on my iPad simply because they use the same Apple ID or something.

Comment: Have you turned on Automatic Downloaded for both devices?

Comment: @fsb that might be it.   I feel dumb, but I guess in my defense, I never ran more than one IOS device from a single Apple ID.   It's a relief if that's all it is.